# How to automatically generate the following combinatorical table?

Tags: tables, programming

The following shows an example of `X` possible tables with constraints that will be specified shortly.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
n & a & b\\
a & n & b\\
n & b & a\\ %<====== updated!
a & b & n\\
n & b & a\\
a & b & n\\
n & b & a
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Image has been updated!**

[image]

### Constraints

- There are only 3 columns.
- There are only 3 characters `n`, `a` and `b`.
- Two adjacent rows must not have character `n` in the same column. Note that the first and last row are not regarded as two adjacent rows. **UPDATE:** For each row other than the first one, the position of `n` is always below `a`.
- The total number of characters other than `n` in the first column **must** always be 3.
- The total number of characters other than `n` in the second column **must** always be 6.
- The total number of characters other than `n` in the third column **must** always be 5.

How can I generate the `X` possible tables?

Comment: a and b don't play a part in the constraint so for every arrangement of the n there are 2^7 ways of adding ab or ba to each of the rows, do you need all those typesetting or is it enough to use an alphabet with n and two a.

Comment: @StiffJokes OK but it's dull, there are 3 arrangements of the n, and then each of those has to be set 128 times with a and b swapped in each row.

Comment: they may be important in the application but they are not important to the mathematics, mathematics is more important than real life.

Comment: @StiffJokes yes but if you dropped the constraints and said print all the 3x7 tables with cells a b or n then there would be 21^3 different tables which would all _mean_ something but it would be pointless to list them all. It's the same here, there are 3 different layouts with 128 copies of each layout by symmetry, showing the three layouts might be informative, typesetting 384 tables is not

Comment: @StiffJokes yes, they do not involve a and b

Comment: ...but now you have duplicate rows. That's okay? It seems to me if you swap `a` and `b` in the last two rows, that'll also give you valid solutions according to the constraints.

Comment: @Werner: You cannot swap `a` and `b` for the last 2 rows because it violates the 3rd constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can ignore the distinction between a and b (as they play no part in the constraint) any feasible layout will trivially have 2^7=128 variants by swapping the a and b on each row (or 4^7=16384 if a row may have 2 a or 2 b)

so there are these possible row types (call them 1 2 and 3)

```
n.. 1
n.. 1
n.. 1
n.. 1
.n. 2
..n 3
..n 3
```

you need to permute this collection so no row type appears in adjacent slots.

If you use all three types in the first three rows, then the remaining 4 rows have to be filled with 1113 which is impossible, so it is easy to see that the only possibilities are

```
1213131
1312131
1313121
```

that is

```
n.. 1
.n. 2
n.. 1
..n 3
n.. 1
..n 3
n.. 1
```

or

```
n.. 1
..n 3
n.. 1
.n. 2
n.. 1
..n 3
n.. 1
```

or

```
n.. 1
..n 3
n.. 1
..n 3
n.. 1
.n. 2
n.. 1
```

then each of those layouts copied 128 times if naa is not allowed or 16384  if it is) by replacing `. .` by `a b` and `b a` or by `a a`, `a b`, `b a` and `b b` depending.

---

With the updated question with the additional constraint the answer is as above except that there are just two copies rather than 128 of each layout, the `. .` on the last row being `a b` or `b a` every other row is determined as n is placed, a is forced by the n on the next row, and b has to go in the remaining slot (assuming the unstated constraint that there is an a and b in every row)

Comment: @StiffJokes well those were simple enough I just wrote them down, in general combinatoril problems usually have a simple solution that may be critically slow or a fast solution that depends on the exact nature of the constraint; for example you could easily even programming in tex, loop through all possible combinations of 1111233 and then check that there were no adjacent values. Coming up with a search path that generates valid results without having to backtrack or discard many invalid ones is harder, but may not be worth it if the search space is sufficiently small. Ask a sudoko player.

Comment: @StiffJokes OK I updated the answer to match.

Comment: True, but then it is no a TeX problem; it is a [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) problem, which is NP-complete. So you cannot expect to find an efficient solution

Comment: So you meant there are 6 tables?

Comment: If `{3,6,5}` is changed to `{3,3,4}`, do you get 24 arrangements?

Comment: @StiffJokes yes 6, with 334 and 5 rows per table yes there are 2*12 arrangements (in the notation above 5 starting with 1, 5 more with 1 and 2 transposed, then 2 starting with 3) multiply by 2 fora b or b a on the last row.

Comment: @Aditya yes exactly, and it also means you ought to find the answer before asking tex to typeset it as with the minor re-wordings the question has undergone since posting the number of solutions varies between 6 and 49152 tables, and you probably need different document designs for those cases:-)

Comment: There is no TeX code?